# Adding value to the arguments object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, arguments

I'm having problems with adding values to the arguments objekt in a JavaScript method.

I'm trying to add an additional success callback to the `Backbone.Model.fetch()` method, my model looks like this:

```
models.Settings = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "path/to/settings.json",

    dataLoaded: function() {
        this.set({
            data: new collections.Data( this.get("data") )
        });
    },

    fetch: function() {
        var
            cb;

        if(!arguments.length) arguments[0] = {};

        if(arguments[0].hasOwnProperty('success')) {
            cb = arguments[0].success;
        }

        arguments[0].success = function() {
            this.dataLoaded();
            if(typeof cb === 'function') cb.apply(undefined, arguments);
        }.bind(this);

        models.Settings.__super__.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

The code works well as long as a value (any value) is passed to `fetch()`. The problem occurs when the arguments object is initially empty. I'm able to set `arguments[0]` and the `success` value, [as I'm supposed to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). But the callback is never run.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arguments` property is an object, not an array, which means that when you set `arguments[0] = {};`, it then looks like (http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/n93wfm8a/)

```
{
    0: {}
}
```

However, `models.Settings.__super__.fetch.apply` expects an array (or at least a `length` property matching the content) and does not get it.

### Solutions

1. Most hackish, set a `length` property :

   ```
   if(!arguments.length) {
       arguments[0] = {};
       arguments.length = 1;
   }
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/n93wfm8a/1/
2. Slightly better, initialize `arguments` with an array

   ```
   if(!arguments.length) {
       arguments = [{}];
   }
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/n93wfm8a/2/
3. Rewrite the whole thing to take advantage of the method's signature `model.fetch([options])` and use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/call)

   ```
   fetch: function(opts) {
       var cb;
       opts = opts || {};

       if (opts.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
           cb = opts.success;
       }

       opts.success = function() {
           this.dataLoaded();
           if(typeof cb === 'function') cb.apply(this, arguments);
       }.bind(this);

       Settings.__super__.fetch.call(this, opts);
   }
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/n93wfm8a/4/

Comment: Right, I knew it was an object, but it looks like an array. I guess I got confused and expected it to behave like an array. I've rewritten the method to look like option 3, thanks.